# Run OCR in Nextcloud with Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nextcloud

I'm using the official Docker image `nextcloud:latest` to run my Nextcloud instance. I managed to install Elasticsearch (on the host) and created an index. Search works so far.

Now I want to OCR PDFs and installed the Tesseract plugin in Nextcloud. However PDFs don't get OCR'd, I suspect it is because `tesseract` isn't available within the official Docker image.

How can I solve this, or do I have to create my own Docker image from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own image? Have you tried installing tesseract inside the container to see if it works?

Comment: @GregL No, haven't given a try yet. I'm wondering if anyone out there is using tesseract with Nextcloud & Docker

Comment: Looks like `nextcloud:latest` is Debian based, which means you should be able to build a new image with an extra `RUN` command, that installs Tesseract with `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all`.